# Regex in python dataframe: count occurences of pattern

Tags: python, pandas, regex, performance, optimization

I want to count how often a regex-expression (prior and ensuing characters are needed to identify the pattern) occurs in multiple dataframe columns. I found a solution which seems a litte slow. Is there a more sophisticated way?

| column_A | column_B | column_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test • test abc | winter • sun | snow rain blank |
| blabla • summer abc | break • Data | test letter • stop. |

So far I created a solution which is slow:

```
print(df["column_A"].str.count("(?<=[A-Za-z]) • (?=[A-Za-z])").sum() + df["column_B"].str.count("(?<=[A-Za-z]) • (?=[A-Za-z])").sum() + df["column_C"].str.count("(?<=[A-Za-z]) • (?=[A-Za-z])").sum())
```

Comment: If you want a solution to improve the timings you need to provide a better testing data. How did you come to the conclusion is slow?

Comment: The regexps can be a bit faster if you replace the lookbehinds with consuming pattern, `(?<=[A-Za-z])` > `[A-Za-z]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension` and `re.search`. You can reduce `938 µs` to `26.7 µs`. *(make sure don't create `list` and use `generator`)*

```
res = sum(sum(True for item in df[col] if re.search("(?<=[A-Za-z]) • (?=[A-Za-z])", item))
       for col in ['column_A', 'column_B','column_C'])
print(res)
# 5
```

Benchmark:

```
%%timeit 
sum(sum(True for item in df[col] if re.search("(?<=[A-Za-z]) • (?=[A-Za-z])", item)) for col in ['column_A', 'column_B','column_C'])
# 26 µs ± 2.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit 
df["column_A"].str.count("(?<=[A-Za-z]) • (?=[A-Za-z])").sum() + df["column_B"].str.count("(?<=[A-Za-z]) • (?=[A-Za-z])").sum() + df["column_C"].str.count("(?<=[A-Za-z]) • (?=[A-Za-z])").sum()
# 938 µs ± 149 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew, Add to your answer, Then I will check

Comment: No offense, you answer is better. I'm fine with you doing timing for me :D

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew, Do I check Timing your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The `str.count` should be able to apply to the whole dataframe without hard coding this way. Try

```
sum(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.count("(?<=[A-Za-z]) • (?=[A-Za-z])").sum()))
```

I have tried with 1000 * 1000 dataframes. Here is a benchmark for your reference.

```
%timeit sum(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.count("(?<=[A-Za-z]) • (?=[A-Za-z])").sum()))
1.97 s ± 54.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```